# Master detail structure with EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following classes in my mvc model and I'm using EF

```
 public class Patient
    {
        [Key()]
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
     }

public class Treatment
    {
        [Key()]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Patient")]
        public int PatientId { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime TreatmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to display the names of the Patients and in the same row the number of treatments they received.

The 2 solutions i can think of but looking for something more elegant:

1. Iterating my Patients and for each count its treatments
2. Group Treatments and count. Then Join between that result and Patient.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found the answer - and it is so simple !!!

```
db.Patients.Include("Treatments").ToList()
```

and then in my view i simply do

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Treatments.Count)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Patient
{
    [Key()]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Treatment> Treatments
 }
```

In your view;

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
    <h1>@item.Name</h1>
    <h2>@item.Treatment.TreatmentDate
}
```

in your query;

```
db.EntityName.Select(p=> new Treatment()
{
    PatientId = p.PatientId,
    .....
...
    Treatments = p.Treatments
});
```

Comment: I don't understand your query. db is not enumerable so how do you "Select" and what is ViewModel?

Comment: sorry, i missed the table name :D

Comment: viewmodel is just a name for your custom viewmodel e.g in your case it's Treatment. A viewmodel is a special kind for class that can pass data required to the view only

Comment: Sorry but it still doesn't make sense to me. I need to return to my view the patient object including the treatments. there are 2 things i'm confused about. 1. I have Treatments property in my Patient class and i don't understand why it isn't populated automatically. 2. In your suggestion - i return anonymous type and i'm not sure how to bind it to my view.

Comment: see this http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3. I hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use ViewModel for your Views . I think this is better practice.Here you can read about it : [What is ViewModel in MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) . Basicly it's simple class with only this properties which you need for your Views. I don't understand your Model very well but I would do something like this

```
    public class Patient
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }// if it's Id it's default Primery Key
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
 public string LastName { get; set; }
     }

public class Treatment
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }// if it's Id it's default Primery Key


        public Patient IdPatient { get; set; } // Your Foreign key

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime TreatmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

with this, one patient may have more then one TreatmentDate . I'm not pro just enthusiast. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, but this is one to man. One patient can have many treatments. I need to display a grid with the patient data + number of treatments he received.